# How to color input border bottom using CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to color a input border bottom when the input is not focus. This is my html code:

```
<input type="number" id="nc" name="days" class="numero" placeholder="" min="0"><br />
```

This is my css code:

```
.numero {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border is red in your example:

```css
.numero {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="nc" name="days" class="numero" placeholder="" min="0"><br />
```

Simply use the shorthand to add a style, size and color and it works.

Now, in order to remove this when it is focused:

```css
.numero:not(:focus) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="nc" name="days" class="numero" placeholder="" min="0"><br />
```

We use the `:not()` functionality with the `:focus` to check if the element in question *is not focused*.

Comment: Why is there need for margin here?

Answer (score 0):

```
.numero {
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
input.numero {
 border-bottom-color:red;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavikbamania/eo81n74c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add some border style:

```
.numero{
  border: 1px, solid;
  border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the border thickness in the css.
You can write that like this

```
.numero {
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

And on focus if you want another color you can like this

```
.numero:focus {
    border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}
```

You can change the value of **transparent** to any other color of your preference.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.numero {
  border-bottom: 2px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="nc" name="days" class="numero" placeholder="" min="0"><br />
```

**for any query please comment. All the best**